# Excel 2016 Powerquery- load to data model stuck in perpetual refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a data connection to an Oracle database. I use a SQL query against through Powerquery. Without making any transformations, I try to load it directly to the data model but it always get stuck after a certain number of rows are loaded (i.e. "13,203 rows loaded") and never completes. I've done this successfully on other tables with powerquery in the past.

What is happening?

edit: there must be something wrong with the table because I am able to load other tables ok. Any ideas on what might be wrong with it?

edit2: more specifically, it might have something to do with the table fields, i omitted certain less relevant ones (14/24 fields) and was about to import rows where rownum <=20000.. will try to increase from there

Comment: ive had similar issue in the past, issue will ly with the table/query etc and probably not power query, but i was importing from sql server not oracle